# How to create an XML Schema that allows one or more <a/> followed by an equal number of <b/>?

Tags: xml, xsd, context-free-grammar, xsd-1.0

I would like my XML instance documents to consist of one or more `<a/>` elements followed by an equal number of `<b/>` elements. Here are some valid instances:

```
<a/><b/>, <a/><a/><b/><b/>, <a/><a/><a/><b/><b/><b/>
```

I want to use XML Schema 1.0 to implement it.

I tried this approach:

```
<xs:group name="context-free-language">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" fixed="a" />
        <xs:group ref="context-free-language" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="b" fixed="b" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Unfortunately, circular group references are not allowed.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

XML Schema 1.0 provides only partial support for context-free grammars. Regrettably, it does not support grammars that require an equal number of a's and b's. On the other hand, it does support some context-free grammars. I wrote an article which explains this: http://www.xfront.com/XML-Schema-1-0-and-Relax-NG-Partially-Support-Context-Free-Grammars.pdf

Comment: The set of valid child sequences defined by any content model in XSD, RNG, or DTDs will be a regular language, not a context-free language.  The example you give in the paper cited conflates the sets of child sequences definable by a schema language with the sets of trees definable with that language; not at all the same thing, and not at all a refutation of the claim that you appear to want to refute.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is to recognize a context-free language.  You cannot do that with a content model in a schema language which requires content models to be regular expressions and thus to define regular not context-free languages.  No schema language currently in wide use allows content models to define context-free languages.

Your options are (1) change your design to work better with the technology at your disposal instead of working against it, (2) use ad-hoc processes (like the XSLT stylesheet suggested by InfantPro'Aravind'), or (3) use assertions in Schematron or in XSD 1.1 to enforce the constraint.

Comment: Why is it that circular complexTypes are permitted, but circular groups are not? You say that XSD does not support context-free languages, so circular groups are not allowed. But don't circular complexTypes result in a context-free language?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by circular complex types, sorry.  In general, it's important to distinguish between the document language defined by a schema as a whole and the child-sequence language defined by a particular content model.  The former is typically a context-free language whose sentences are sequences of characters which satisfy the context-free grammar of the XML spec.  The latter is a regular language whose sentences are sequences of elements (or equivalently of element names).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with XSD 1.0. I think not possible with 1.1 as well.

There are alternative methods like Schematron. Or one can use XSLT to transform and output the result. which inturn can be validated to see if XML is valid.

I will give a brief on this 2nd method:

Sample Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a/>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <b/>
</root>
```

Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <validation>
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--Output 'true' if count is equal .. and 'false' otherwise-->
        <xsl:when test="count(a)=count(b)">
          <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </validation>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since count(a) equals count(b) This outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<validation>true</validation>
```

And that inturn will be validated against:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="validation" type="xs:boolean" fixed="true"/>
</xs:schema>
```

which will pass in this case since `<validation>` node has value `true`

note: XSLT just creates a transformed copy which I am using for extended validation, it doesn't modify the original input.

Answer (score 1):

InfantPro'Aravind' states incorrectly:

```
This is not possible with XSD 1.0. I think not possible with 1.1 as well.
```

In fact it's quite possible using XSD 1.1 assertions. Just define a content model that allows any number of As followed by any number of Bs, and then add the assertion

```
<xs:assert test="count(A) = count(B)"/>
```

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of it. Anyways the OP wanted to use 1.0 alone, so I didn't perform much research on 1.1. I am curious to know if any workaround is possible to deal with XSD 1.0 for this requirement. I have suggested XSLT(as ad-hoc) and want to know more options. Thank you..

Comment: No, it's not possible in 1.0. Michael SpMcQ explains why: it's not a "regular language" (that's a technical term from the theory of grammars).